# Can you only get so many decoration items on one cartridge via mystery gift in Pokémon GSC?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal, pokemon-stadium-2

I reset time on my silver edition to get unlimited mystery gifts.

For the past ~100ish runs I didn't get even one decoration item, so I like to know if there is a limit how many decoration items you can have on one cartridge.

I use Pokémon Stadium 2 to get my mystery gifts, if that changes anything.

The decoration items have no use outside of just looking good.